# Is there a session type variable i could use with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am writing to a generic list where each item holds two values, I'm writing the variables name and valCount to the list.

I have to posts in my page load and i think this is the reason i only get the value 0 returned.

The value i am having issues with is valCount in the post `$.post("Dashboard/UserValuationGet"` the val count is declared before that method and set to 0.

Even if i set the code to valCount = 5 in the post method that value is still lost, How could i keep that value? is there a way to use session in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) 
        {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet);
            var table = obj.Table;
            var countUsers = 0;
            lis = '';
            for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) 
            {
                var array = table[i];
                if (array.Active == 1) 
                {
                    var name = array.Name;
                    valCount = 0;
                    $.post("Dashboard/UserValuationGet", {}, function (dataSet1) 
                    {
                        var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet1);
                        var table1 = obj1.Table;
                        for (var i = 0, len = table1.length; i < len; i++) 
                        {
                            valCount += 1;
                        }
                    });
                    lis += '<li class="subitem1"><a href="#">' + name + '<span>' + valCount + '</span></a></li>';                    
                    countUsers = countUsers + 1;
                }
            }
            $("#UserList").empty().html(lis);
            $('#userCount').html(countUsers.toString());

        });
    });
```

Comment: Sessions are held server-side so it's not possible to access them via client-side script.  You could use cookies or localStorage instead.  LocalStorage is very easy to use... [Click here to find out more about localStorage](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archer got that bang on.

If you are insistent on server storage, it would be make server round-trip calls and save variables on session and retrieve when needed. Use $.ajax() to set or get data